# SQL insert statement using pyodbc and MS Access ERROR 07002

Tags: python, pyodbc

Im lost on this error.

```
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Using the below code gives the error.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;{FIL=MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\Users\James\Documents;DBQ=C:\Users\James\Documents\Database1.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

      cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Loan_vehicle_data (Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) values (test , 
   test , test)""")
```

Ive tried different variations of the `INSERT` statement but still cant get it to work.
Could someone please clarify for me the correct way to write the `INSERT` statement. I have read that you need to use `cursor.commit()`  but that doesn't seem evident in this library so I'm assuming that's redundant? I also read that you need triple `"""` at the beginning and the end of the statement but according to what I read in the docs https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor that doesn't seem so?

Here's the full traceback..

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "<ipython-input-90-00d386f93670>", line 92, in add_new_loancar_to_DB
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO [Loan_vehicle_data](Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) values (test , test , test)""")
    pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the string value `'test'` into each of the three columns?

Comment: @GordThompson Thats correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit

```sql
INSERT INTO Loan_vehicle_data (Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) values (test , test , test)
```

and `test` is not enclosed in single quotes it is interpreted as a column name. When Access SQL encounters a column name (or similar) that it doesn't recognize it *assumes* that it is a parameter placeholder. Therefore it comes to the conclusion that you have a parameter named `test` in your query but you have not provided any parameter *values*. Your query will work as intended if you use

```sql
INSERT INTO Loan_vehicle_data (Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) values ('test' , 'test' , 'test')
```

You could also do this:

```py
text_to_insert = "test"
sql = "INSERT INTO Loan_vehicle_data (Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cursor.execute(sql, text_to_insert, text_to_insert, text_to_insert)
```

(Yes, you'll need to repeat the parameter value three times because pyodbc only supports positional – not named – parameters.)